# What's the difference between malloc and tc_malloc?

Tags: gcc, tcmalloc

for a code main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    void* p = malloc(1000);
    free(p);
    return(0);
}
```

1st compile:  `gcc main.c -o a.out`

2nd compile:  `gcc main.c -ltcmalloc -o a.out`

1st use glibc stdlib，2nd use tcmalloc

and I can write main.c like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <google/tcmalloc.h>
int main()
{
    void* p = tc_malloc(1000);
    tc_free(p);
    return(0);
}
```

3rd compile: `gcc main.c -ltcmalloc -o a.out`

3rd is surely use tcmalloc

Is the 2nd and 3rd compile the same ?

I know tcmalloc support more functions like `tc_malloc_size` / `tc_valloc`, I guess use tc_* functions is better option to write main.c, so I have more functions ?

I can't find any man page for functions like tc_valloc / tc_new / tc_newarray / tc_valloc / tc_pvalloc

Comment: http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html

Comment: But there's nothing about tc_valloc or tc_cfree functions manpage. I want more than basic malloc/calloc/realloc/free/malloc_size.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourcecodebrowser.com/google-perftools/1.4/windows_2google_2tcmalloc_8h.html

i find this man page about all tcmalloc functions

Comment: 1) It isn't a man page.  2) The linked document doesn't even explain what the tc_* functions do. 3) It doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

When tcmalloc is loaded, malloc and free are aliased (see gcc documentation of __attribute alias) to tc_malloc and tc_free.

So your 2nd run and 3rd will be same.

The intention of tc_malloc and tc_free is to be able to use tcmalloc versions of malloc directly regardless of what other allocators are present.